Doesn't generate any file when use VideoWriter in JupyterLab (there is no any error on console)
I use Jetson Nano to connect my camera, I'm sure the camera can show on my windows.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('video_name.mp4', fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))

while (cap.isOpened() == True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow("test", frame)
        writer.write(frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord("q"):
            break

cap.release()

Some Nano can generate video, but some can't, and it doesn't show any error on console.
I keep checking my camera width and height, they are correct.
Is there any suggestions or solutions?
Python: 3.6.9
Jetson Nano: AT017-NAO-EN70
I try to use fopen to generate a text file, and it worked.
And I try to change video type to '.avi' and fourcc(*'XVID'), but it still can't generate any video file and no error.

check writer.isOpened() -- check print(os.getcwd()) -- print(cv.getBuildInformation()), video IO section, what does it say?

thanks your response. 
writer.isOpened() == True and os.getcwd() is in the same dir~ 
this is video I/O print:
Video I/O:
DC1394:                      NO
FFMPEG:                      NO
avcodec:                   NO
avformat:                  NO
avutil:                    NO
swscale:                   NO
avresample:                NO
GStreamer:                   NO
v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

no ffmpeg. that is an issue. OpenCV uses it for most video file IO. you should investigate why your build of OpenCV does not have ffmpeg. if you built it yourself, the cmake configure step probably didn't find ffmpeg. if you installed it as a binary package, contact the package maintainer. -- without ffmpeg, your only option is OpenCV's built-in writer capabilities, which is exactly .avi container and MJPG codec.

I found some information related to what you said. I try to reinstall my OpenCV and it can generate video. Thanks a lots!!
